# AJAX callback in a form element not working after an AJAX load in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, drupal-7

I am trying to load a form inside a boostrap modal through AJAX ,with another AJAX callback in it. The form is loaded through a menu_hook with a delivery callback where I set the js and css necessaries. 
The problem is that, after the AJAX callback to load the modal, the AJAX callback for the select list does not work, and I think is because the scripts are not executing, I tried to eval() them but it is not working either.

This is a general explanation of what I have till now:

1. Menu_hook that returns the html for the form and the scripts and css
2. Button with id

   ```
   <button type="button" id="show-modal" class="btn btn-warning"></button>
   ```
3. JQuery to show the loading modal when the id of the button is clicked and to trigger the JavaScript function for AJAX load

   ```
   $("#buy-hours").click(function () {
       $('#loading-modal').modal("show");
       _load_ajax(link_to_menu_hook, '#modal-body-wrapper');
   }
   ```
4. JavaScript to load the html through the menu_hook1 and replace it in the loading modal

   ```
   function _load_ajax(url, wrapper) {

       var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
           if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {

               //loads the html
               document.querySelector(wrapper).innerHTML = mlhttp.responseText; 

               var newElement = document.createElement('div');
               newElement.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

               var scripts = newElement.getElementsByTagName("script");
               for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; ++i) {

                   var script = scripts[i];
                   eval(script.innerHTML);

               } else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {

                   alert('There was an error 400 in _load_ajax');

               } else {

                   alert('something else other than 200 was returned');

               }
            }
       };

       xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
       xmlhttp.send();

   }
   ```

** I am loading the modal with Javascript and not with JQuery because when I use load() or $.ajax() the console.log outputs "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.", and still does not work. By loading with Javascript I don't get any error in the console.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just FYI you get that warning when using jQuery as you've set `async: false`. You can easily set it to `true` and get rid of the warning. Also note that your code is missing a `'` which will be causing a syntax error.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Totally correct about the `'` I forgot to put it here. I also tried to set `async: true` but I still got the synchronous error and it did not work either :/

Comment: No I mean *remove* `async: false`. You should never use that

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry, I meant that I tried to set `async: true` , edited.